# showing that two distribution functions are the same

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{++}$ which is twice differentiable and non-constant. I want to show that if 
$$\int g(x)\,\text{d}(\Phi(x;0,\Sigma)-\Phi(x;0,\tilde\Sigma))=0, $$
then 
$$\Phi(x;0,\Sigma)=\Phi(x;0,\tilde\Sigma).$$
$\Phi(x;0,\Sigma)$ is a multivariate normal distribution with mean zero and variance $\Sigma$. $x$ is a random vector (number if $n=1$).

I guess this is true statement, I am not sure how I should show it. If there is a counter example, I wish to see that.

Comment: What if $g(x)=x$?  DId you mean instead to ask if the difference of integrals vanishes for all $g$, then the 2 distributions are the same?

Comment: but it maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{R}_{+}$

Comment: Ah, you want non-negative  function.  What if $g$ is a constant plus and oddfunction, and non-negative, such as $g(x)=2+\sin(x)$.  Then the integrals are the same but yet...